# Triggering pipeline with API

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am triggering my ci pipeline with Microsoft API. Along with trigger I am sending which branch of my repo to be triggered.

Pipeline is checking out my branch and building with my specified branch but the entry in CI pipeline is with master.

https://dev.azure.com/AAA/BBB/_apis/pipelines/1234/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1
with body data like below

```
{
   "stagesToSkip":[],
   "resources":
    {
      "repositories":
       {
         "repo": { "refName": "feature/test" }
       }       
     }
}
```

The Pipeline triggered and has entry like below shown in image with master but since I am triggering with my test repo why it is master ?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW8By.png)

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the self repo along with your repo like below

```
"self": {"refName": "feature/test"}
```

So pipeline will trigger with test branch